# Failed to unlock account *account number* (no key for given address or file)

Tags: go-ethereum

I've been at this for hours, I can't figure out what to do. So some years ago I created an ethereum address using geth. Between then and now, my PC was swiped due to some software problems, and now I'm trying to access my address. I've reinstalled geth, chocolatey, etc.. as per the instructions on their website. I am not 100% sure that I used these programs the first time around, however commandlines etc sound very familiar, so I'm almost sure that these were the programs I used to create my address.

I'm currently trying to do this:

geth account update (address)

Which prompts me to insert password. No matter what I type at this stage (I could just hit enter, or random letters etc..), I get the phrase in the title,

Failed to unlock account *account number* (no key for given address or file).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?? Getting very frustrated at this, I can't understand what to do, and obviously it means that I'm currently without access to my account..

Thanks so much for any help, appreciate it.